# How to make index.html appear in svelte npm run build

Tags: javascript, npm, svelte

Hi guys i am new to Svelte and i have a question.

I have made a small app in svelte that runs smoothly in dev.

But when i am running `npm run build` for production
the output in the public folder are 3 items`bundle.css`
`bundle.js` and `bundle.js.map`
There is no index.html
Can anyone please help me because as it seems the public folder should have the index.html in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public folder should contain a subfolder named "build", inside that folder is where the bundle files should be located.  Your static assets, the index.html file, and service-worker.js (if used) should reside in the public folder along side the build folder.

Setup a base project again and look for the index.html file in the public folder before writing a single line of code.

```
$ npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project
$ cd my-svelte-project
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```

Comment: Yeah the structure is as you said but this wasnt the problem i was addressing. The build folder must contain as i suppose all the necessary js and static files for production. I dont know how recreating an empty template will help in my situation tbh.

Comment: The workflow for svelte is to first run "npm run build" and then copy all objects inside the public folder to your static hosting bucket.  This includes the build folder as well as all the objects outside the build folder but inside the public folder.  Re-creating the starter project was a check to ensure there were no errors in the base configuration on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The [starter template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) assumes the *index.html* and all other static files (favicon, images, ...) are already in your public folder. They do not get any special treatment from the build script. If you want to copy extra files during build you can use special plugins for that.

[rollup-plugin-copy-assets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-copy-assets) could be an option

Comment: So if i want to take all the necessary items for production i take the items in build folder and the index html outside of this folder? In order to paste it in web host directory?

Comment: This is the right answer. OP may have assumed that public should be gitignored and that its content is generated at build time. That's not the case. Instead, public should be part of your repo, the index.html, global.css and favicon.png (and anything else) should remain in there and the subfolder build is the only thing that gets .gitignored and built at compile time

Answer (score 1):

So i found my answer.
After i builded the proj,
i pasted in the webhost all the items from public folder(assets,build,rest of items) and it worked .
It was an issue with host also.